# Libraries to Minimize differences between IE & Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

are there any libraries out there to minimize the differences of the behavior between IE and firefox... or there is someways to achieve that....

if not then what things in `HTML` & `CSS` & `JavaScript` & `jQuery` i should be looking put for that can cause cross browser compatibility issues... my concerns are Firefox and IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

, which fixes some stuff in IE. Between that and using jQuery properly and being somewhat careful, I do not have many issues with IE.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of differences are you trying to avoid? If these are differences in CSS rendering, then there's little you can do if some instruction is interpreted differently by different browsers. As for difference in DOM objects etc, then jQuery or PrototypeJS should hide most of differences in DOM.